# How to save test result of each group in separate file in phpunit

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit

I am running phpunit tests in groups parallely. I want to save the result of each group in separate files as it is overriding the last result. For example,

I am running command:

```
parallel phpunit --log-junit result.xml --group group1 group2 group3
```

In this case result.xml shows only `group3` test results. I need `result1.xml` for `group1`, `result2.xml` for `group2` and so on.

Please can someone help me in this?

Comment: Please someone guide me.. I need to fix this urgently.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be:

```
stage('Unit test groups') {
    parallel {
        stage('Group 1 Tests') {
            steps {
                phpunit --log-junit group1_result.xml --group group1
            }
        }
        stage('Group 2 Tests') {
            steps {
                phpunit --log-junit group2_result.xml --group group2
            }
        }
    }
}
```